# Iterate through an array in a map in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to use an array of keys to extract a map, then extract values from an array in the map, without completely recreating the map.  My two data structures looks like.

```
var keys = ["key1","key2","key3"]

var data = {
"key1": {
    "target": "hostname",
    "datapoints": [
        [12, 1.42472334E9],
        [13, 1.424723355E9],
        [14, 1.42472337E9]]},
"key2": {
    "target": "hostname",
    "datapoints": [
        [15, 1.42472334E9],
        [16, 1.424723355E9],
        [17, 1.42472337E9]]}}
```

I'm trying to extract the data points to place them in into two arrays for graphing based on the key.  Trying to iterate like:

```
for (var k in key)
    for (var v in data[key][datapoints])
```

Is obviously not the correct approach.  Is there a better way to get the data without tearing apart the map?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is two arrays.  Of all the datapoints in the key.  So an array of x which is the content of all the first part of the first entry in the final array and y which would be the second entry.  The final result, for key one would be two objects that look like.
   ` var key1.x_values = [12,13,14]`
   ` var key1.y_values = [1.42472334E9,1.424723355E9,1.42472337E9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browsers javascript console (press F12) to see the output in the demo.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ev0gncmh/)

```
var keys = ["key1","key2","key3"]

var data = {
"key1": {
    "target": "hostname",
    "datapoints": [
        [12, 1.42472334E9],
        [13, 1.424723355E9],
        [14, 1.42472337E9]]},
"key2": {
    "target": "hostname",
    "datapoints": [
        [15, 1.42472334E9],
        [16, 1.424723355E9],
        [17, 1.42472337E9]]}

}
//loop through the array named keys (mind that k is an index/integer)
for (var k in keys){
    //check if data has "key" as property (ie: key3 does not exist in data)
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(keys[k])){
        //loop through the array datapoints which is a property of the object named data 
        for ( var i =0; i< data[keys[k]]["datapoints"].length; i++){
          console.log(data[keys[k]]["datapoints"][i]); //outputs an array with 2 elements
        }
    }else{console.log(keys[k]+" does not exist in data")}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of the datapoints, you can do something like `data.key1.datapoints[0]`. This will give you an array of the datapoints stored under the key1.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array `keys` and then extract the `datapoints` like so:

```
for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var datapoints = data[keys[i]].datapoints;
    // do whatever you want to do with the datapoints. 
    // It's not clear from your question.
}
```